# How to change the background color of an input field when text is entered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new with Javascript and jQuery, and can't seem to indentify the reason why my code acts like it does.

I have created two seemingly identical functions to change the background color of an input field.
Their goal is to turn the background color of the given input field to the color `#00FF7F` if anything is typed in the field. And if not, the field should be transparent.

Code JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input1 = $("#logindata1");
    var $input2 = $("#logindata2");

    function onChangeInput1() {
        $input1.css("background-color", "#00FF7F");
        var value = $.trim($(".form-control").val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input1.css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    function onChangeInput2() {
        $input2.css("background-color", "#00FF7F");
        var value = $.trim($(".form-control").val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input2.css("#background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    $input1.on("keyup", onChangeInput1);
    $input2.on("keyup", onChangeInput2);       
});
```

css:

```
#loginbox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25%;
}

.logindata {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 290px;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
}

.form-control {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: 55px;
    width: 288px;
    border-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    border: solid 2px #00FF7F;
    transition: 0.25s ease;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}

.form-control:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #2E8B57;
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #00FF7F;
}
```

Simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>Test</title>

        <!-- Stylesheet link -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css">

        <!-- jQuery link -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/vendor/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="loginbox">
              <div class="logindata" id="logindata1">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="logindata" id="logindata2">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Javascript link-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </body>
```

On the jsbin above, try typing in both the Username and Password field to see how they react differently.

Images of what happens. Didn't want to include all images here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFHs1.jpg

I realize there probably is a way to compromise my js/jquery into 1 function that each input field calls instead of have a function for each.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If both of these fields are required, here's a much simpler solution using CSS only.

Add the attribute `required` to your `<input>` tags and then use the pseudo-class `:valid`.

```
.form-control:valid {
  background-color: #00FF7F;
}
```

---

**Code snippet:**

```css
#loginbox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
.logindata {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 60px;
  width: 290px;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
}
.form-control {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 55px;
  width: 288px;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 2px #00FF7F;
  transition: 0.25s ease;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
}
.form-control:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #2E8B57;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #00FF7F;
}
.form-control:valid {
  background-color: #00FF7F;
}
```

```html
<div id="loginbox">
  <div class="logindata" id="logindata1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
  </div>

  <div class="logindata" id="logindata2">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7vzjz2u5/3/

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.change-background').on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $.trim($this.val());

    // toggleClass can be provided a bool value,
    // If we provide true we add class, if false we remove class
    $this.toggleClass('filled-background', value.length !== 0);
  }).change();
  // We also want to call a 'change' event on 
  // all inputs with the change-background class just incase the page has
  // pre-filled in values
});
```

Instead of listening for the `keyup` event and then running a function, just create a listener on the `change` event, also if we just apply one class to all inputs we want the background colour to change on, we can just create one listener which will do it for any input with the class `change-background`.

Html

```
<div id="loginbox">
  <div class="logindata" id="logindata1">
    <input type="text" class="change-background form-control" placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <div class="logindata" id="logindata2">
    <input type="password" class="change-background form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
</div>
```

Css (the extra class for background color)

```
.filled-background {
  background-color: #00FF7F;
}
```

### Also side note

listening for `keyup` is back, someone may want to copy and paste their username and password and if they do this it won't trigger an `keyup` event if they use right click and paste.

Comment: excelent approach. you also can replace the `if` statement for a simple `$this.toggleClass('filled-background', value.length !== 0);`

Comment: @robsonrosa yes damn I forgot you can provide a bool in `toggleClass` :D cheers will update answer

Comment: Thank you a ton for your reply! :)
It works wonderfully - The comments helped me clearly understand what is happening in the code, so thank you very much for helping me learn :)

Comment: @Alex that is great to hear :), also if any of these are the correct answer, could you please tick the appropriate one, thank you.

Comment: @Canvas Hey, sorry my reply is delayed - I've done so now :)
I've ticked a CSS solution, because it was the one that worked best for me, but all the js/jquery answers have given me a better understanding of listen events, so thank you :D

Comment: @Alex not reason to apologize :D We are all here to help each other learn, such is knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Your code clears the background color when the length is 0.  The way it checks the length is with this snippet of code:

```
var value = $.trim($(".form-control").val());
```

The selector `$(".form-control")` will select all elements with the CSS class of `.form-control`.  This is a problem because there is more than one of them; in this case, it will always return the value from the first element found.

You should change the code to check for the specific control by searching by ID, like so:

```
var value = $.trim($("#logindata1 input").val()); //get user ID
var value = $.trim($("#logindata2 input").val()); //get password
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some minor mistakes, but no worry. We can fix it.

### First Problem

Other answers are pointing something important: you are trying to get the value selecting all elements with `form-control` class.

`var value = $.trim($(".form-control").val());`

You can do it, replacing your selector by your already declared variables `$input1` and `$input2`. This way:

```
var value = $.trim($input1.val());
var value = $.trim($input2.val());
```

### Second

Ok. First problem solved. The second problem is in your second function. You trying to set an invalid css: `$input2.css("#background-color", "transparent");`

When should be: `$input2.css("background-color", "transparent");` (without `#`).

### Next One

Nice. Next one. The id's you are setting `logindata1` and `logindata2` are on your divs. So, you are wrongly trying to get the value of the div instead the value of the input. you can fix your selector by appending `input`, this way:

```
var $input1 = $("#logindata1 input");
var $input2 = $("#logindata2 input");
```

### Finally

So, finally, it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input1 = $("#logindata1 input");
    var $input2 = $("#logindata2 input");

    function onChangeInput1() {

        $input1.css("background-color", "#00007F");
        var value = $.trim($input1.val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input1.css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    function onChangeInput2() {
        $input2.css("background-color", "#00007F");
        var value = $.trim($input2.val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input2.css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    $input1.on("keyup", onChangeInput1);
    $input2.on("keyup", onChangeInput2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value check is not right.  With your jQuery, you are checking the value of both inputs every time.

Try checking the single inputs that you are interested in instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $input1 = $("#logindata1");
    var $input2 = $("#logindata2");

    function onChangeInput1() {
        $input1.css("background-color", "#00FF7F");
        var value = $.trim($input1.val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input1.css("background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    function onChangeInput2() {
        $input2.css("background-color", "#00FF7F");
        var value = $.trim($input2.val());

        if (value.length === 0) {
            $input2.css("#background-color", "transparent");
        }
    }

    $input1.on("keyup", onChangeInput1);
    $input2.on("keyup", onChangeInput2);       
});
```