# Change the background color of input text based on conditional value

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create an input text field, and when values like 1, 2, 3 are typed in the text field the background color of the text field will change to Red, Yellow, and Green, respectively. I have find some clue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540302/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-an-input-field-when-text-is-entered)
but unable to get my desired output (Conditional format). Not that great in js, so any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/zcwf1mtg/

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways but this is one way how you could do it:

```js
const colors = document.querySelectorAll('.colors');

for (let color of colors) {
  color.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
    if (this.event.target.value == 1) {
      this.event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
    else if (this.event.target.value == 2) {
      this.event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
    else if (this.event.target.value == 3) {
      this.event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
    else {
      this.event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'inherit';
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="colors">
<input type="text" class="colors">
<input type="text" class="colors">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing alternative code. It works too :)

Comment: How can i do this to multiple input fields though? if there are more than 100 fields

Comment: @ABS2019 I have changed the code. If it helped you, please mark this answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

**Method-01:**
Using **switch:**

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="color" />
```

JS:

```
function changeColor(e){
    var color;

    switch(e.target.value){
        case 1:
            color = "red";
            break;
        case 2:
            color = "yellow";
            break;
        case 3:
            color = "green";
            break;
        default:
            color = "white";
    }
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("input", changeColor);
```

**Method-02:**
Using **if else:**

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="color" />
```

JS:

```
function changeColor(e){
    var value = e.target.value;
    var color;

    if(value == 1){
        color = "red";
    }
    else if(value == 2){
        color = "yellow";
    }
    else if(value == 3){
         color = "green";
    }
    else {
         color = "white";
    }

    e.target.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

document.getElementById("color").addEventListener("input", changeColor);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the code. It works!! Thanks